# HTML JavaScript document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

First, my English not very well when you read this post, I'm sorry.

Recently I met one problem, I try to get table ID from buttons send the ID to function do compare. And in the function, I have created an Array to stored the table ID. But I can't successfully compare Id used array or string.

Can somebody teach me how to solve or do this thing?

Here is my code
HTML:
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QELPW.jpg)

JS:[JavsScrpit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxjgA.jpg)

```js
var arrTabID = ["tSec1", "tSec2", "tSec3", "tSec4", "tSec5", "tSec6", "tSec7"];

function displaySetting(id) {
  /*var tabID = document.getElementById(id);*/
  /*if(document.getElementById(id)==arrTabID[0])*/
  if (document.getElementById(id) == "tSec1") {
    if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "none") {
      doucment.getElementById(id).style.display == "block";
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
          document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    } else {
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
    }
  }
  /*if(document.getElementById(id)==arrTabID[1])*/
  else if (document.getElementById(id) == "tSec2") {
    if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "none") {
      document.getElementById(id]).style.display = "block";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      if (i != 0) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
      }

    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
  }
}
/*if(document.getElementById(id)==arrTabID[2])*/
else if (document.getElementById(id) == "tSec3") {
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "none") {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      if (i != 0) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
      }

    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
  }
}
}
```

```html
<table class="table-content">
  <tbody>
    <!--Section 1-->
    <div>
      <table id="tSec1" name="NtSec1" style="display:block;" height="450px">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left;"><br>
              <img src="../pic/voiceIcon.png" alt="voiceIcon" height="50" width="50">
              <audio controls>
           <source src="../sound/media_1/media1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
     </audio>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 1.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 2.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 3. </h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 4. </h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 5.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3>&sect;.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!--Section 2-->
    <div>
      <table id="tSec2" name="NtSec2" style="display:none;" height="450px">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left;">
              <img src="../pic/voiceIcon.png" alt="voiceIcon" height="55" width="55">
              <audio controls>
           <source src="../sound/media_1/media2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
              </audio>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 6.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3>&sect;</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 7.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3>&sect;</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 8.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3>&sect; </h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 9.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!--Section 3-->
    <div>
      <table id="tSec3" name="NtSec3" style="display:none;" height="450px">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="hidden-phone" style="text-align:left;"><br>
              <img src="../pic/voiceIcon.png" alt="voiceIcon" height="50" width="50">
              <audio controls>
           <source src="../sound/media_1/media3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
              </audio>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 10.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 11.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3>&sect;</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 12.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 13.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3>&sect;</h3><br></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!--Section 4-->
    <div>
      <table id="tSec4" name="NtSec4" style="display:none;" height="450px">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="hidden-phone" style="text-align:left;">
              <img src="../pic/voiceIcon.png" alt="voiceIcon" height="55" width="55">
              <audio controls>
           <source src="../sound/media_1/media4.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
              </audio>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 14.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3>&sect;</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 15.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 16.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 17.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!--Section 5-->
    <div>
      <table id="tSec5" name="NtSec5" style="display:none;" height="450px">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left;">
              <img src="../pic/voiceIcon.png" alt="voiceIcon" height="55" width="55">
              <audio controls>
           <source src="../sound/media_1/media5.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
              </audio>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 18.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 19.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 20. </h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 21.</h3><br></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!--Section 6-->
    <div>
      <table id="tSec6" name="NtSec6" style="display:none;" height="450px">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left;">
              <img src="../pic/voiceIcon.png" alt="voiceIcon" height="55" width="55">
              <audio controls>
           <source src="../sound/media_1/media6.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
              </audio>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 22.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> &sect; </h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 23.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3>&sect;</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 24.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 25. </h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!--Section 7-->
    <div>
      <table id="tSec7" name="NtSec7" style="display:none;" height="450px">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left;">
              <img src="../pic/voiceIcon.png" alt="voiceIcon" height="55" width="55">
              <audio controls>
           <source src="../sound/media_1/media7.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
              </audio>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 26.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3>&sect;</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 27.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 28.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 29.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>Page</h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <button style="height:50px;width:50px;font-size:30px;" onclick="displaySetting('tSec1')">1</button>&nbsp;
      <button style="height:50px;width:50px;font-size:30px;" onclick="displaySetting('tSec2')">2</button>&nbsp;
      <button style="height:50px;width:50px;font-size:30px;" onclick="displaySetting('tSec3')">3</button>&nbsp;
      <button style="height:50px;width:50px;font-size:30px;" onclick="displaySetting('tSec4')">4</button>&nbsp;
      <button style="height:50px;width:50px;font-size:30px;" onclick="displaySetting('tSec5')">5</button>&nbsp;
      <button style="height:50px;width:50px;font-size:30px;" onclick="displaySetting('tSec6')">6</button>&nbsp;
      <button style="height:50px;width:50px;font-size:30px;" onclick="displaySetting('tSec7')">7</button>
    </div>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you for your help. Best regard.

Comment: If you ask a question you should bring the code you post in a readable form. The snippet editor has a `tidy` button that does most of the work for you automatically. And the code should be free of syntax errors, so that it is clear that the problem is not the syntax error. (`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`)

Comment: we can not under stand what exactly you want to do ! please explain briefly your question

Comment: @Rain the other thing is ` doucment.getElementById(id).style.display == "block";` should be ` doucment.getElementById(id).style.display ="block";`

Comment: I'm Sorry, cause troubled. This is my first time to ask a question in here.

I want to send the table ID through the button and enter JS.
In the JS, judge the table ID
Let it do a display or hide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You compare an HTML object and a string.

```
if(document.getElementById(id)=="tSec1")
```

Use `if(id == 'tSec1')` instead.

And then there is a typo in

```
document.getElementById(id]).style.display = "block";
```

and your loops do nothing.

If you want the function to set display to *block* for an element with given id and set all other elements to display *none* you could do it like this:

```js
var arrTabID = ["tSec1", "tSec2", "tSec3", "tSec4", "tSec5", "tSec6", "tSec7"];

function displaySetting(id) {
  var tabID;
  var index = arrTabID.indexOf(id); // index of given id in array arrTabID
  for (var i = 0; i < arrTabID.length; i += 1) {
    tabID = document.getElementById(arrTabID[i]); // for ids in arrTabID
    if (i == index) {
      tabID.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      tabID.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table-content">
  <tbody>
    <!--Section 1-->
    <div>
      <table id="tSec1" name="NtSec1" style="display:block;" height="450px">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left;"><br>
              <img src="../pic/voiceIcon.png" alt="voiceIcon" height="50" width="50">
              <audio controls>
              <source src="../sound/media_1/media1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
             </audio>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 1.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 2.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 3. </h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 4. </h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 5.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3>&sect;.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!--Section 2-->
    <div>
      <table id="tSec2" name="NtSec2" style="display:none;" height="450px">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left;">
              <img src="../pic/voiceIcon.png" alt="voiceIcon" height="55" width="55">
              <audio controls>
              <source src="../sound/media_1/media2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                          </audio>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 6.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3>&sect;</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 7.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3>&sect;</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 8.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3>&sect; </h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 9.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!--Section 3-->
    <div>
      <table id="tSec3" name="NtSec3" style="display:none;" height="450px">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="hidden-phone" style="text-align:left;"><br>
              <img src="../pic/voiceIcon.png" alt="voiceIcon" height="50" width="50">
              <audio controls>
              <source src="../sound/media_1/media3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                          </audio>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 10.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 11.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3>&sect;</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 12.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 13.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3>&sect;</h3><br></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!--Section 4-->
    <div>
      <table id="tSec4" name="NtSec4" style="display:none;" height="450px">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="hidden-phone" style="text-align:left;">
              <img src="../pic/voiceIcon.png" alt="voiceIcon" height="55" width="55">
              <audio controls>
              <source src="../sound/media_1/media4.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                          </audio>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 14.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3>&sect;</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 15.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 16.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 17.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!--Section 5-->
    <div>
      <table id="tSec5" name="NtSec5" style="display:none;" height="450px">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left;">
              <img src="../pic/voiceIcon.png" alt="voiceIcon" height="55" width="55">
              <audio controls>
              <source src="../sound/media_1/media5.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                          </audio>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 18.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 19.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 20. </h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 21.</h3><br></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!--Section 6-->
    <div>
      <table id="tSec6" name="NtSec6" style="display:none;" height="450px">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left;">
              <img src="../pic/voiceIcon.png" alt="voiceIcon" height="55" width="55">
              <audio controls>
              <source src="../sound/media_1/media6.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                          </audio>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 22.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> &sect; </h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 23.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3>&sect;</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 24.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 25. </h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!--Section 7-->
    <div>
      <table id="tSec7" name="NtSec7" style="display:none;" height="450px">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left;">
              <img src="../pic/voiceIcon.png" alt="voiceIcon" height="55" width="55">
              <audio controls>
              <source src="../sound/media_1/media7.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                          </audio>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 26.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3>&sect;</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 27.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 28.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3> 29.</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>Page</h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <button style="height:50px;width:50px;font-size:30px;" onclick="displaySetting('tSec1')">1</button>&nbsp;
      <button style="height:50px;width:50px;font-size:30px;" onclick="displaySetting('tSec2')">2</button>&nbsp;
      <button style="height:50px;width:50px;font-size:30px;" onclick="displaySetting('tSec3')">3</button>&nbsp;
      <button style="height:50px;width:50px;font-size:30px;" onclick="displaySetting('tSec4')">4</button>&nbsp;
      <button style="height:50px;width:50px;font-size:30px;" onclick="displaySetting('tSec5')">5</button>&nbsp;
      <button style="height:50px;width:50px;font-size:30px;" onclick="displaySetting('tSec6')">6</button>&nbsp;
      <button style="height:50px;width:50px;font-size:30px;" onclick="displaySetting('tSec7')">7</button>
    </div>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your suggestions.
I will try to change, and execute your suggestions. :)

Comment: You're welcome.  We were all beginners at one time. Try to understand the js code. I didn't change anything in your HTML. If you have any question about it, please ask.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Do you have a suggested learning website? About JS
I know w3schools this website...

Comment: I wouldn't recommend w3schools. A very good site imho is [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). There are docs and tutorials and the quality is really good. If you meet problems with anything you try, there is [SO](https://stackoverflow.com) of course! ;)

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation!!

Answer (score 1):

What I get from your post is.. you are trying to search in array of table id's, if exist you want to perform some action

you can do this by code given below.

```
var arrTabID = ["tSec1", "tSec2", "tSec3", "tSec4", "tSec5", "tSec6", "tSec7"];

function displaySetting(id) {
  var tabID = document.getElementById(id);
 debugger
  if (id == arrTabID.find(x=>x==id)) {
    if (tabID.style.display == "none") {
      tabID.style.display == "block";
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
          tabID.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    } else {
      tabID.style.display = "block";
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Your loop is just setting display to *none* six times to the same element.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your suggestions.
There is a place, I don't know what it is doing.
--> if (id == arrTabID.find(x=>x==id))
Can you please explain this line?